# Precision mismatch Plot vs FindRoot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

When plotting a function that depends on `FindRoot`, the function is not rendered.
I can calculate individual values. I sometimes get errors:

> FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function (70.0001
>   -((10+10/(1+Power[<<2>>])) Log[x/10])/Log[10]==45) is less than WorkingPrecision (20.`).

This is similar to bug reported in ["Is FindRoot wrong about its WorkingPrecision"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88889/18476). I have tried changing the `WorkingPrecision` and precision of input boundaries to no avail, Code:

```
attArea[x_] := 10*(1/(1 + Exp[(-5/250)*(x - 250)])) + 10
ca[Le_] := FindRoot[(Le - (attArea[x] * Log[10, x/10]) == 45), {x, 300}]
Plot[ca[LL], {LL, 70, 75}]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `ca[Le_] := 
 x /. FindRoot[(Le - (attArea[x]*Log[10, x/10]) == 45), {x, 300}]`

Comment: `Table[{LL,ca[LL]}, {LL, 70, 75,1/10}]` , then `ListPlot`

Comment: The fix suggested by Karsten works.   That was quick! Thanks also for the fallback Table Solution from George2079.

Answer (score 2):

Answered: The solutions from Karsten is to prepend the FindRoot with x /. which is a replacement see ReplaceAll in documentation. I am assuming this forces the expression to be evaluated before entering the plot function.

Comment: Great job answering your own question based upon comment! Please write Karsten's solution on your answer. Don't make the reader have to read the comment. Show an example.